# Tomcat | Exclude Access Log from catalina.out, keeping in localhost_access_log.<date>.txt

Tags: tomcat

i have the following configuration in server.xml that enable access_log

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="common"/>
```

my logging.properties is

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
```

I just want to exclude access_log from catalina.out, but keeping it in dedicate localhost_access_log..txt file.
Is this possibile? How?